# ActiveDirectory: Query Performance

Tags: c#, performance, active-directory

I'm trying to read all users from an Active Directory. However, this is rather slow (300 users take around 10 secs). Here's the code:

```
public void LoadADUsers()
{
   using (var Context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyServer"))
   {
      using (var Searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(Context)))
      {
         var DirectorySearcher = (DirectorySearcher)Searcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher();
         DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
         DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
         DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");

         foreach (var Result in Searcher.FindAll())
         {
            var Entry = (DirectoryEntry)Result.GetUnderlyingObject();
            string FullName = (string)Entry.Properties["cn"].Value;
            string AccountName = (string)Entry.Properties["samAccountName"].Value;
            ADUsers.Add(new ADUser(Entry.Guid.ToString(), FullName, AccountName));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now, the creation of the `Context` object takes around 7 secs, probably because this is where the connection to the server is established. Is there any way to speed this up?

Additionally, the loop takes around 2.5 secs, probably meaning that there is still communication with the AD server going on. I expected that the `Searcher.FindAll()` call would receive all users at once, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any way to enforce that behavior, or to otherwise speed up the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clear on why you insist on **twice** fetch the underlying object (`DirectorySearcher`, which you then don't even use at all, and `DirectoryEntry`) - if you're already using the more advanced one anyway...... this will cost time, too!!

I would do this like so:

```
using (var Context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyServer"))
using (var Searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(Context)))
{
    foreach(var result in Searcher.FindAll())  // those are 'Principal' objects...
    {
         // cast to "UserPrincipal"
         UserPrincipal up = result as UserPrincipal;

         // if successful - use the object properties directly on the 'UserPrincipal'
         // absolutely no point and benefit in "downcasting" to a 'DirectoryEntry' !
         if (up != null) 
         {
             string FullName = up.DisplayName;
             string AccountName = up.SamAccountName;

             ADUsers.Add(new ADUser(up.Guid.ToString(), FullName, AccountName));
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, this speeds up the loop quite a bit - thanks! Although I had to use "up.DisplayName" instead of "up.FullName". Any idea about the creation (and/or connection establishing) of the PrincipalContext? And how to set the "PropertiesToLoad" on the PrincipalSearcher without using the underlying DirectorySearcher? It's not that I'm not using that object at all...

Comment: @csoltenborn: you cannot set any *properties* to load on `PrincialSearcher` - you always get back the whole `UserPrincipal` (or whatever you're searching for) which is a small subset of the most commonly used properties on the `DirectoryEntry` - so most often, this works just fine

Comment: @csoltenborn: I believe the creation of the `PrincipalContext` just does take some time initially - not sure if there's any "magic" way to get this to happen faster. Should be faster on the second attempt, I would think

Comment: Yes, the 2nd time is indeed much faster, but that doesn't help much in my use case... Thanks anyways for your help!